# Merge cells with the following blank ones

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code for automatically reading in data from a closed workbook.

I am having some problems with the formating. The problem is when I am reading in some text in a row (each text is followed by six empty cells), and I am trying to merge the following blank cells.

```
For Row = 1 To NumRows
    For Column = 3 To LastColumn
        Range(Cells(Row, Column).Address, Cells(Row + 1, Column + 6).Address).Merge
    ...
```

This merges everything into one cell. If I have 10 cells containing text, I want ten merged cells.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does not work (or does not behave as expected) ?

Comment: Say I have 70 cells... The first contains text, the next six nothing, eight conatins text, and so on. This should give me 10 merged cells, but instead, it merges every 70 cells to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does merge your whole cells because you parse 1 by 1.
Meaningly, what your program do is:

- Parse cell `A1`
- Merge with the next 6 cells --> cells `A1:A6` are merged
- Parse cell `A2`
- But... hey, this will try to merge cell `A2` to `A6` !

What you can do:

1. Use the `step` option on your for loops - see [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/for-loop-step.htm) for more information
2. Check if the cell is already merged when you parse it. If it is, then use the `continue` statement in your for loop

Regards,